# Accessing Data Extension field values - Journey builder custom activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, custom

I am working on custom activity in Journey builder where, I need to access the values of the fields from Data Extension as `inArguments`. I read about data binding from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) and used the below syntax to access data extension field values:

```
{{Contact.Attribute.DE_NAME.FirstName}}
```

But, I receive empty string in the `FirstName` field and I am sure there is value present for this field in DE.

**config.json**

```
{
  "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
  "metaData": {
    "icon": "img/img_1.png",
    "iconSmall": "img/img_2.png",
    "category": "message"
  },
  "type": "REST",
  "lang": {
    "en-US": {
      "name": "Test custom activity",
      "description": "Testing custom activity"
    }
  },
  "arguments": {
    "execute": {
      "inArguments": [
        {
          "firstName": "{{Contact.Attribute.DE_NAME.FirstName}}"
        },
        {
          "lastName": "{{Contact.Attribute.DE_NAME.LastName}}"
        },
        {
          "emailAddress": "{{Contact.Default.Email}}"
        }
      ],
      "outArguments": [],
      "url": "https://xyz.ngrok.io/activities/execute",
      "verb": "POST",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "format": "json",
      "useJwt": false,
      "timeout": 10000
    }
  },
  "configurationArguments": {
    "applicationExtensionKey": "test-activity-custm-wwq",
    "defaults": {
      "activity": "0"
    },
    "save": {
      "url": "https://xyz.ngrok.io/activities/save",
      "useJwt": false
    },
    "publish": {
      "url": "https://xyz.ngrok.io/activities/publish",
      "verb": "POST",
      "body": "",
      "useJwt": false
    },
    "validate": {
      "url": "https://xyz.ngrok.io/activities/validate",
      "verb": "POST",
      "body": "",
      "useJwt": false
    },
    "stop": {
      "url": "https://xyz.ngrok.io/activities/stop",
      "useJwt": false
    }
  },
  "wizardSteps": [
    {
      "label": "Select anything",
      "key": "1"
    },
    {
      "label": "Confirm Settings",
      "key": "2"
    },
    {
      "label": "Save Settings",
      "key": "3",
      "active": false
    }
  ],
  "userInterfaces": {
    "configModal": {
      "height": 250,
      "width": 600,
      "fullscreen": false
    }
  }
}
```

**Received inArguments in Execute API :**

```
{"inArguments"=>[{"firstName"=>""}, {"lastName"=>""}, {"emailAddress"=>"testemail+62@gmail.com"}]
```

Is anything I am doing wrong, please help me.

Thanks..

Comment: Are these values part of the entry event and therefore available via event data? If not, is the data extension correctly linked to an attribute group in contact builder?

Comment: @MarkusSlabina, Thanks, I missed it. Now, I can get the values of the Data Extension fields after creating a population in Data designer by linking a field in DE with the `Contact Key`.

Comment: Please post it as an answer, So, others can easily find the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help! Just added everything to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If those values are part of the entry event, you can access them using the following expression:

```
{{Event.<YOUR ENTRY EVENT DEFINITION KEY>.\"<EVENT DATA ID PATH>\"}}
```

If not, you need to link the data extension correctly to an attribute group in contact builder, for it to be available for data binding in the arguments of your custom activity. In that case your expression is correct.

**Related documentation:**

- [How Data Binding works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm)
- [Create an Attribute Group](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_designer/create_an_attribute_group/)

**Code Example:**

- [Custom Split Activity that queries Service Cloud data (including documentation)](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)

  - [config.json](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit/blob/master/public/config.json)
  - [customActivity.js (added inArguments in save-function)](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit/blob/master/public/customActivity.js)

Comment: Hi Markus, could you show an exact string for the entry event that will be rendered at the runtime?
{{Event.<YOUR ENTRY EVENT DEFINITION KEY>.\"<EVENT DATA ID PATH>\"}}
Is it like `{ "FirstName":"{{Event.TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_AUTOMATION_STUDIO.\"TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_DE.FirstName\"}}" }`

I am struggling with getting the inArguments values of the entry event

Comment: As I don't know your event definition key and data path this is a bit hard, but you can see this in the referenced article [How Data Binding works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm). An example is: `{{Event.my-custom-product-entry-event-key.ProductId}}`. I'm using it for a Salesforce Data Event and looking up data from one of my custom objects in Service cloud. In that case passing the Id of this object looks like this: `{{Event.my-sf-entry-event-key.\"CustomObject__c:Id\"}}` The last part is the column name in the event's DE.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! 

Event definition key: 'TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_AUTOMATION_STUDIO'.
DE external key that is connected with event: 'TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_DE'.
Field (Text, 100) in DE I want to retrieve: 'FirstName'.
But still I cannot get a value in inArguments payload.
Basically I created a journey in MC, created a Contact Data Entry Event. I know it will be deprecated, but I use it temporary for testing purposes, i.e. firing an event from Automation Studio, it's much easier to inject contacts into a journey.

Comment: If you only wan't to pass data from the entry event directly (as you are using a contact data entry event) this could be done using `{{Event.TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_AUTOMATION_STUDIO.FirstName}}`.

Comment: I have created a new question to discuss this issue - [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185792/accessing-entry-event-data-journey-builder-custom-activity)

Comment: @MarkusSlabina, Can you please tell me how to get the `ENTRY EVENT DEFINITION KEY`? I can't able to find it?

Comment: @GokulM As stated in the readme of my code example, you can finde the entry event definition key in Journey Builder > Entry Sources, when clicking on the entry event and checking the summary then. Usually the key is on the bottom of the summary modal.

Comment: @MarkusSlabina thanks man regarding {{Event.my-sf-entry-event-key.\"CustomObject__c:Id\"}}, didn't know that if it's from salesforce data event it should be like this \"CustomObject__c:Id\"

Comment: @imajmdf I'm happy my answer could help you ;) If it did, you could upvote it to show your appreciation and others see this is a solution to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: upvoted already, thanks man!