# Accessing Entry Event Data - Journey Builder Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

**Background**

I am developing a simple custom activity for JB. There are lots of gotchas apparently. I have read the following sources from cover to cover and still cannot make it all together:

> [How Data Binding Works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm)
>
> [Accessing Data Extension field values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180526/accessing-data-extension-field-values-journey-builder-custom-activity/180555?noredirect=1#comment279880_180555)
>
> [Accessing subscriber profile attribute values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180963/accessing-subscriber-profile-attribute-values-journey-builder-custom-activity)

I need to access the values of the fields from Data Extension as inArguments. This Data Extension is linked to the Journey Entry Event. Hence I should be accessing entry event attributes basically.

I created a journey, added an Entry Source of type "Contact Data Entry Event". Data Extension I am trying to pull data from is linked to this Entry Event.

Entry Source Name: **TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_AUTOMATION_STUDIO**

[image]

[image]

Data Extension External Key: **TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_DE**

Data Extension field name: **FirstName**

[image]

**config.json:**

```
     "arguments": {
         "execute": {
            "inArguments": [
                 { "Contact.Key":"{{Contact.Key}}" },
                 { "FirstName":"

{{Event.TEST_CUSTOM_EVENT_AUTOMATION_STUDIO.FirstName}}"
 },
                 { "FirstName":"Test" }
             ],
             "outArguments": [
             ],
             "url": "https://zapier-jb-test.herokuapp.com/jb/activities/send-to-zapier/execute/",
             "verb": "POST",
             "body": "",
             "header": "",
             "format": "json",
             "useJwt": false,
             "timeout": 10000
         }
     },
```

**Received inArguments in Execute API :**

```
{  inArguments: [ 
    { 'Contact.Key': 'customevent1' },
    { FirstName: '' },
    { FirstName: 'Test' },
], ...}
```

**Question**

How can I access these data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found where the bug was. I should have used the "real" EVENT DEFINITION KEY instead of its NAME. When you are in a journey you won't see this value. For this you need to go to Entry Sources and find your Event there.

[image]

So now it works!

**config.json:**

```
     "arguments": {
         "execute": {
            "inArguments": [
                 { "Contact.Key":"{{Contact.Key}}" },
                 { "FirstName":"{{Event.ContactEvent-72af1529-1d7d-821e-2a08-34fb5068561d.FirstName}}" }
             ],
             "outArguments": [
             ],
             "url": "https://zapier-jb-test.herokuapp.com/jb/activities/send-to-zapier/execute/",
             "verb": "POST",
             "body": "",
             "header": "",
             "format": "json",
             "useJwt": false,
             "timeout": 10000
         }
     },
```

**And the API Output:**

```
{  inArguments: [ 
    { 'Contact.Key': 'customevent1' },
    { FirstName: 'Foo1' }
], ...}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the `ENTRY EVENT DEFINITION KEY`? I can't able to find it in my summary of the entry source audience?